# How to make asset can be download in WSO2 ES

Tags: wso2, wso2-es

I visit the site https://store.wso2.com, when I choose one connector(for example: Jenkins), it show the detail page, and it has the **Download connector** Link button!! I think the site is build from WSO2 ES.
My question is how can make the asset can be downloaded? I try the WSO2 Enterprise Store 2.0 version, but I can't find anyway to achive it.

Answer (score 2):

You can achive this using asset extensions in WSO2 ES-2.0.0 version.

In a default pack [HOME]/repository/deployment/jaggeryapps/store/themes/store/partials/asset.hbs files renders the asset details page. You can override it as well as sub partials used in that file by asset type.

Copy [HOME]/repository/deployment/jaggeryapps/store/themes/store/partials/assets.hbs to [HOME]/repository/deployment/jaggeryapps/store/extensions/assets//themes/store/partials/asset.hbs

In this file add change to UI elements to point to a downloadable URL.

ex: https://github.com/wso2/product-es/blob/1.0.1/modules/apps/store/extensions/assets/ebook/themes/store/partials/asset-utilization.hbs#L11

You can read more about WSO2 ES extension model [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ES200/Working+with+the+ES+Extension+Model)